# Spine.js model - resource creation before id is updated

Tags: spine.js

Guys,

I have two models, `Notebook` and `Note`. Note belongs to a notebook and notebook has many notes.

In my application I have a very common 3-columns view, 1st col lists notebooks, and 2nd col lists the notes corresponding to the selected notebook, and the 3rd col contains a form of the currently selected note.

[image]

In Spine, I didn't use the relation module. Every time the user selects a notebook, I call `get /notebooks/:id/notes` to fetch the corresponding notes of the selected notebook and render the note list, and when user click to create a new note, I will create a Spine object of note model with the current selected notebook_id and call `save()`. It works fine with the existing notebooks.

But there's a problem when a user creates a new notebook. If user click to create a new note inside this new notebook, before the notebook create ajax finishes, I don't have the actually notebook id from the database. So I think I have to wait for the `notebook create` ajax call back, before then I will block the user from clicking to create a new note.

But from Spine documentation,  Alex said: `Waiting for a server response goes against the whole concept of an asynchronous user interface`.

So, what's the correct way to do this? Am I doing it right?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is way more complicated to not wait for a server response. It is up to you to decide when the non-blocking UI is worth the extra development effort and code complexity. In this case it shouldn't be terribly hard to trigger updating the reference ids on notes when the id on the notebook is updated, however it sounds like you wouldn't want to allow attempts to persist the note before that happens. That is doable without a blocking UI though.